# Defining class name using php and regex matching in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I want create an dynamic HTML page were the class name is defined by the php program

**My code:**

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTd(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ca");
    for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
          elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideTd()">
<select name="retailerselect" id="retailerselect" onchange="retailerSelect()" width: 66px;> 
  <option selected="selected" size="10" >--SELECT--</option>
  <option class="ca">hi</option>
  <option class="ca">this</option>  
          <?php $connect = " yes-ad";?>
                <option class="<?php echo $connect;?>"> <?php echo $connect;?> </option>

  </select>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I the HTML script i would have hide the value of option tag in the class  "ca"

**Input:**

```
$connect:"yes-ad"
```

**Output:**

```
class="ad" value in the option ="yes-ad"
```

Sorry if my script is wrong i am a newbie in HTML or is there any other way to do this

**Edit:**
Simplified the script

**The Output iam getting now**

[image]

***I want it to show yes-ad with its class***

Comment: I do not at all understand what you are trying to do but the variable definition ` $connect = "yes-ad" ` in your code is outside of the php tags `<?php` and `?>`.

Comment: @Bowdzone is this correct now

Comment: The input for $connect will be given from python variable i have to match the variable with reg-ex the matched variable should be given to class and the whole variable should go to value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideTd(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("ca");
    for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
          elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="hideTd()">
<select name="retailerselect" id="retailerselect" onchange="retailerSelect()" width: 66px;> 
  <option selected="selected" size="10" >--SELECT--</option>
  <option class="ca">hi</option>
  <option class="ca">this</option>  
          <?php $connect = " yes-ad";?>
                <option class="<?php echo $connect;?>"> <?php echo $connect;?> </option>

  </select>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: <option class="<?php echo $connect?>"> <?php echo $connect?> </option> is this possible

Comment: @yd600lty like he said there is no need for the brackets

Comment: @VigneshKalai you should look on PHP file as HTML only that you can inject PHP code when you open PHP tag <?php ?> there is also short tag support and can be enabled in the php.ini config file, these short tag make your coding easier and shorter,e.g. <?=$param?> will do the same thing as <?php echo $param?>

Comment: in case you dont see anything it probably fatal error, and display errors is disabled, add the following lines to the top of your page:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: because of this JS line: elements[i].style.display = 'none';  It hides all ca classes

Comment: now i have removed the display none now also the yed-ad is not being printed

Answer (score 3):

The php code is wrong.
There should not be `{` and `}` .Just remove them.

And to change the classname, just do like this:

```
<option class="<?php echo $connect;?>">....</option>
```

Comment: @VigneshKalai You want to change the class name?

Comment: yes i want to change the class name and assign a value

Comment: i want it to be like this <option class="<?php echo $connect;?>"> <?php echo $connect;?> </option>  is this possible

Comment: although the code looks not beauty, but it works, you can do this.

Comment: But nothing is shown only --select-- is shown the drop down

Comment: because of this JS line: elements[i].style.display = 'none';